# SQL nested in form. access table from schema

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have N schema A, B, C,... and in all of this schema i know there is a table named XXX. I would like to display all the XXX tables for all the schema.
The problem is that i don't know the schema name and how many schema are in the DB.

```
select *
from ( select distinct table_schema 
       from information_schema.tables 
       where 
         table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') and 
         table_schema not like 'pg_toast%' and 
         table_schema not like 'public' ).XXX
```

The nested query works. I can retrieve the list of my schema. but the .XXX doesn't work.

Thanks for help.
Diego

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: If you only want the schema *names* , not the table *contents* for xxx,  then: `table_schema not like 'public' ).XXX` -->> `table_schema not like 'public' AND table_name like 'XXX' )  zzz`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use table inheritance, not sure if that would work for you.

If I have two such tables:

```
CREATE TABLE s1.xxx(id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO s1.xxx VALUES (1, 'one');

CREATE TABLE s2.xxx(id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO s2.xxx VALUES (1, 'two');
```

I could create a new table and make the two tables children of the new table:

```
CREATE TABLE xxx(id integer PRIMARY KEY, val text NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE s1.xxx INHERIT xxx;
ALTER TABLE s2.xxx INHERIT xxx;
```

Then I can just `SELECT` from the new table:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx;

┌────┬─────┐
│ id │ val │
├────┼─────┤
│  1 │ one │
│  1 │ two │
└────┴─────┘
(2 rows)
```